# nouislider angular 2 format tooltips

Tags: angular, format, slider, tooltip, nouislider

I want to convert the tooltip values from seconds to a date. But there's a catch, there's an initial date (startTime), and I want to add the tooltip values (seconds) to this date, and show it in the tooltip.

That is, if my initial time is 05:00:00 and I move the left handle 5 seconds, it should show 05:00:05.

The format in the tooltips is working, I have managed to change the value as date or even to add strings to it.

I'm working in Angular 2, <strike>when I call the method `this.formatTooltipTimeDate(value)`, I get the error.</strike>

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatTooltipTimeDate' of
>   undefined

This is now working by the change suggested by @Stefan Svrkota , but, now I can only see "undefined" in both tooltips.

I added a message in the console, where I can see that the date is correctly formatted as a string, but the value returned is still undefined.

Tooltip configuration:

**component.ts**

```
    this.sliderConfig = {
      start: 0,
      connect: true,
      range: {
        min: 0,
        max: rangeTime
      },
      format: {
        from: Number,
        to: (value) => {                    
          this.formatTooltipTimeDate(value).subscribe(
            data => {
              console.log('new tooltip format ', data);
              return data;
            }
          );
        }
      },
      step: 1
    };


  formatTooltipTimeDate(seconds): Observable<string>{
    let t = new Date(this.startTime);
    let newDate;
    t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + seconds);

        // Formate Date: HH:MM:SS
        let hour = this.formatTwoDigits(t.getHours());
        let minute = this.formatTwoDigits(t.getMinutes());
        let second = this.formatTwoDigits(t.getSeconds());
        newDate = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
        return Observable.of(newDate);
  }
```

**component.html**

```
  <nouislider class="nouislider" [config]="sliderConfig" [tooltips]="[ true, true ]" [(ngModel)]="someRange" (change)="event($event)"></nouislider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out , the problem was the return of a string as an observable.

I changed format like this (I don't make a subscription anymore):

```
  format: {
    from: Number,
    to: (value) => {   
      let t = new Date(this.startTime);
      t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + value);   
      return this.formatTooltipTimeDate(t);
    }        
  }
```

The method formatTooltipTimeDate does not return an observable anymore:

```
  formatTooltipTimeDate(date){
        // Formate Date: HH:MM:SS
        let hour = this.formatTwoDigits(date.getHours());
        let minute = this.formatTwoDigits(date.getMinutes());
        let second = this.formatTwoDigits(date.getSeconds());
        date = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;

        return date;
  }
```